Flutter Firestore Case-Insensitive Search Not Working
I'm developing a Flutter app where I'm using Firestore as my backend database. I'm implementing a search functionality where users can search for categories by their titles. However, I'm encountering an issue where the search is case-sensitive, and I want it to be case-insensitive.
I've tried converting the search text to lowercase and using it in the Firestore query, but it's not returning the expected results. Even when I add .toLowerCase() to the search query, it doesn't seem to work as expected.
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('categories')
            .where('title', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: widget.searchText)
            .where('title', isLessThanOrEqualTo: widget.searchText + '\uf8ff')
            .snapshots(),

One thing I would like to add is that when I add .tolowercase() it does not search it shows no results!
Below is the complete code if you wanna have a look at it:
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('categories')
            .where('title', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: widget.searchText)
            .where('title', isLessThanOrEqualTo: widget.searchText + '\uf8ff')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const SpinKitCircle(
              color: primaryBlue,
              size: 32,
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> productcategories = snapshot.data!.docs
                .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
                .toList();
            if (productcategories.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No products found',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }

            return Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: productcategories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String categoryID = snapshot.data!.docs[index].id;
                    Map<String, dynamic> productData = productcategories[index];

                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: size.height * 0.095,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Container(
                            child: Image.network(
                              productData['categoryImage'].toString(),
                              width: 60,
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            productData['title'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: size.width * 0.032,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          subtitle: FutureBuilder(
                            future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('users')
                                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                .collection('products')
                                .where('category', isEqualTo: categoryID)
                                .get(),
                            builder: (context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> productSnapshot) {
                              if (productSnapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return Text(
                                  'Loading....',
                                  style: customTextgrey.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                                );
                              } else if (productSnapshot.hasData) {
                                int itemCount =
                                    productSnapshot.data!.docs.length;
                                return Text(
                                  '$itemCount items',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: size.width * 0.032,
                                      color: primaryBlue),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Text(
                                  'Error',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: size.width * 0.032,
                                      color: primaryBlue),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                          trailing: SizedBox(
                            width: size.width * 0.34,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      showBottomSheet(
                                          categoryID,
                                          productData['categoryImage']
                                              .toString(),
                                          productData['title']);
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Edit',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: size.width * 0.03),
                                    )),
                                TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      await _deleteCategory(categoryID);
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Delete',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: size.width * 0.03,
                                          color: Colors.red),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const SpinKitCircle(
              color: primaryBlue,
              size: 32,
            );
          }
        });


Is your "title" field stored in lower case in Firebase? Queries are case-sensitive, therefore even if your query text is convert it to lowercase if the data stored in Firestore has upper and lower cases it will not find it

hi the title stores how users enter it. IF THE user stores it in upper case it is stored in upper case

If you call .toLowerCase() in your application code, the query will not return the desired results since the titles start with a capital letter in the database. To solve this, you have to create another field in your document, called for example titleToLowerCase, and search against it.

Hey Syed. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Hi sir I wanted to ask where should i add titleToLowerCase. This is e commerece so should i add the title to lowercase withing the document that has the title? and i want the search to not case about case sensitivity.. like if the user types L or A it should show all products with L or A in it upper case or lower case should not matter

Yes, you should add this new field within the document that contains the title. To get the desired results, you should call .toLowerCase() when you query as you can always get what you need. If this approach doesn't solve your problem, then you should consider implementing a more advanced search feature.

i have added them but how do i update my query according to the database now i have created a key of lowercase in my databse and also for uppercase

You should change .where('title'... to .where('titleToLowerCase'.... Give it a try and tell me if it works.

it works thanyou sir!!!
